# When I try to solve a equation python only uses integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a new project, it is like a math site. I am trying to create a program that will solve equations.

It is working normally with simple equations for example `x + 10 = 12`, however when I try to do equations with exponents like `x**2 + 3 = 5` it doesn't give me anything. I believe that this python code doesn't work with decimals.

Code in below

```
import math 

def solve():
 x = -1000
 while x < 1001:
 if x**2 + 1 == 4:
  print("x = " + str(x))
 x += 1

solve()
```

I expect the output to be `1.73205080757` and `-1.73205080757`.
However I get nothing (Because it couldn't find an answer).

Comment: You should use a library such as SymPy for that. `x += 1` will only ever allow `x` to be an integer

Answer (score 2):

You're expecting an answer that's between 1 & 2. You're starting at -1000 and incrementing by 1. So you'll go from -1000 to 0 to 1 to 2 to 3....skipping over your expected answer altogether.

You should be using something like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

(With floats i.e `x=1.0`)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, your minimal step is `1` (x was increased by `x += 1`), hence `x` can be only integer. There is no such integer can full-fill your condition `x**2 + 1 == 4`

Answer (score 0):

this will only check integer values from x = - 1000 to x = 1000, ie it will ask is -1000 the answer? No, is -999 the answer? No etc, and never try 1.7 or 1.73 or 1.73...! The answer is a float not an integer, so the method as written can't possibly get it. You would need somehow to iterate closer and closer answers. This is a question of mathematical algorithm design I think, you can first look up math formulae how to approximate quadratic solutions (probably some 17th century mathematician did the formula!), then try convert this formula into Python. If you don't know about float, int, "duck typing" in Python difference, try googling this also may help you.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't give nor will give the solution you expect because of two reasons:

1. The while loop increments x by 1 at each step, so there is no way x can be a float number. It will always be an integer.
2. The solution you expect for this case has infinite decimals, so even if x were a float, it could never be the desired value in order to solve the equation.

As a remark/suggestion, if you are trying to solve an equation in python, why don't you just create a function that give the result to an equation of the form: x^2 +a = b. The following code should be an example:

```
import numpy as np

def solve_prueba(a,b):

    """ 

    The function solves a function of the form x^2 + a = b 

    """

    x = np.sqrt((b-a))

    return x
```

This way is much more time effective rather than create a while loop has to pass over all the numbers with their infinite decimals to give the solution to a given equation.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to start at `-1000` and go up to `1000` since you are looking for a value from `1` to `2`. In your code, you increment with 1, which means that `x` will never be a decimal value. You could however increment with a very small number (e.g.) `x += 0.0000000000001`.

If you use this small increment, you should probably use `math.isclose()` instead of `==`, because small float values tend to have some precision error. Like in your expected answer where you expect the outcome to be `1.73205080757` altough `1.73205080757**2 + 1 == 4.000000000003889` and not `4`.

Using `math.isclose((x**2 + 3), 4, rel_tol=1e-9)` like this, it checks if the calculation from `x**2 + 3` is somewhere close to `4` with a tolerance of `1e-9`, which would output the values that you expect from this equation.

So for your code:

```
import math 

def solve():
    x = -1000
    while x < 1001:
    if math.isclose((x**2 + 1), 4, rel_rol=1e-9):
        print("x = " + str(x))
    x += 0.0000000000001

solve()
```